# How to fix "Unexpected null value" error in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, web, instagram, mobile-application

I am creating a clone of the Instagram app and I am getting a "Unexpected null value" error in the feed screen of the app. Can you help me out fix the error? Here is the code of the app: https://github.com/zfr18/Instagram_Clone

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: your question is hard to figure out, add details to it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.